# Display < script.... code on cloned website

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-4

I wish to block access to my website from some cloned website.

I want to ad in my website, an obfuscated javascript version of this code:

```
if (window.location.hostname != 'mysite.com') 
{
   window.location.href = 'https://google.com'; 
}
```

**But it is impossible**, because in the cloned page **disappears every mention to** `<script` and it is impossible to put on the page the full js code

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
//.js code go here
    </script>
```

I tried to use HTML entity encoding and change `<script` with `&lt;script` but this just phrase in html and the JS are not loaded in the page.

To be as accurate as possible, I talk about these websites:

- Real web: **pepelatino.com**

  Clone web: **opengem.org**

If you inspect this 2 websites, you will see that in the REAL web they find many `<script` instances but in the CLONE site, all this disappear but at the end of the page you will see an other `<script` loaded by this clone.

The script used for this website is laravel 4

**Any help is really appreciated.**

Comment: Sounds like the clone site is working to circumvent your attempts, which makes sense. Your better approach is probably the legal one - a DMCA complaint for copyright violations.

Comment: What about .htaccess level or even DNS/IP level blocking?

Comment: DNS/IP blocking It is very difficult because they use cloudflare

Comment: On the other hand they have made at least 200 copies with 200 different domains and many ip, all behind cloudflare.